# Fails to install the Angular CLI in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I can not install the Angular CLI in Ubuntu 16.04.
After entering the `sudo npm install-g angular-cli`, it takes a long time to load and write.

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.13.0-37-generic 
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "angular-cli" 
npm ERR! node v4.2.6 
npm ERR! npm v3.5.2 
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/ng 
npm ERR! code EEXIST 
npm ERR! Refusing to delete /usr/local/bin/ng: ../lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng symlink target is not controlled by npm /usr/local 
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/ng 
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again. 
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request: 
npm ERR! /home/dosxanzada/WebstormProjects/meanauthapp/npm-debug.log
```

[image: npm errors]

node version: v9.7.1,
npm version: 3.5.2

Comment: npm ERR! Linux 4.13.0-37-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "angular-cli"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/ng
npm ERR! code EEXIST

npm ERR! Refusing to delete /usr/local/bin/ng: ../lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng symlink target is not controlled by npm /usr/local
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/ng
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/dosxanzada/WebstormProjects/meanauthapp/npm-debug.log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
npm cache clean
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm install -g -f angular-cli
ng --help
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to manually delete "ng" folder from "/usr/local/bin".

So run the following command:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/ng
```

And then install Angular Cli again:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

If the second command still doesn't work, try to force install adding `-f`:

```
sudo npm install -g -f @angular/cli
```

Other users that facing the same problem maybe could have to delete `/usr/bin/ng` instead of `/usr/local/bin/ng`.

Comment: For me, the only solution was going to the directory, open the folder as a root, and then, delete the directory. Thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Are you using nvm because you mentioned node version as `v9.7.1` but the error is  referring to node version `ERR! node v4.2.6`. Verify that you are running at least node `6.9.x` and `npm 3.x.x` by running `node -v` and `npm -v` in a terminal/console window. And if you are using nvm then please install node latest version using following command:

```
nvm install --lts
```

Then run `nvm use {version no}` eg. `v9.7.1`
Then try installing angular cli.

Note: If you open new terminal then nvm will switch the node version to the deafult vesrion. So u may get such errors. For avoding this you can set the latest version as default node vesion for nvm by using following command.

```
nvm alias default {version no} eg. v9.7.1
```

Comment: This will work only if you are using nvm. Otherwise just update node version to latest one.

Answer (score 0):

i also faced same issue on windows, i tried below steps :

1. [npm ERR EEXIST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGNuD.png)
2. so i went through that [Refusing to delete path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoMwn.png) & deleted @angular/cli folder manually.
3. now, In command-prompt/terminal executed the cmd to install angular cli globally: ***npm install -g @angular/cli***

its worked fine for me, so you also try this in same way :-)